# How to remove Google Smart Lock saved passwords in Instagram?

Tags: google, password, instagram, smart-lock

How do I remove these accounts and saved passwords from Google Smart Lock in Instagram?

[image: smart lock]

I have tried all different methods to remove it but no use. I have deleted all of my Chrome passwords, Google passwords, Instagram clear all data, turn off auto-fill for Google, but still this doesn't go away.

Moreover, I don't have access to these accounts in Instagram too. Please help me remove this Smart Lock popup along with its saved accounts.

Comment: By "Google passwords", did you mean Settings - Google - (Select your Google Account) - Manage your Google Account - Security tab - Password Managers (under "Signing in to other sites") - (Search for Instagram)?

Comment: Yes. Not just instagram, ive deleted everything in hope of this going away but it doesnt. Also ive deleted in password manager of google too.